# Apache Camel Multithreaded Throttling Error

Tags: apache-camel

When Im sending multithreaded request to a route with throttling sometimes I get NPE exception. if route has no throttling everything is fine. Do I need to sycnhronize some where when using throttling in multithreaded environment ?

route ends with success:

```
from("direct:start").log("executed ${body}").to("mock:result");
```

route with throttling ends with NPE sometimes:

```
from("direct:start").throttle(method(ThrottlingTester.class, "getMessagesPerSecond")).timePeriodMillis(1000).rejectExecution(true).log("executed ${body}").to("mock:result");
```

Code sending requests:

```
MockEndpoint resultEndpoint = resolveMandatoryEndpoint("mock:result", MockEndpoint.class);
resultEndpoint.expectedMessageCount(6);
resultEndpoint.setResultWaitTime(3000);
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
@Override
public void run() {
    template.sendBody("direct:start", "<test1> </test1>");
}
}).start();
}
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
@Override
public void run() {
    template.sendBody("direct:start", "<test2> </test2>");
}
}).start();
}
resultEndpoint.assertIsSatisfied();
```

Code calculates throttling value:

```
public synchronized static long getMessagesPerSecond(Exchange exchange){
    if(exchange.getIn().getBody(String.class).indexOf("test2")>0)
        return 1000;
    return 1;
}
```

Error :

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Throttler$TimeSlot.access$002(Throttler.java:158)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Throttler.calculateDelay(Throttler.java:123)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.DelayProcessorSupport.process(DelayProcessorSupport.java:156)
```

Using Camel version 2.15.3

Comment: What version of Camel do you use?

Comment: Using Version 2.15.3

Comment: Try upgrade to latest 2.15.x, or 2.16.x where the throttler has been improved for concurrency.

Comment: I will try it, thank you.